# Google Map API v3 - create search bounds from two previously queried points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

There are a lot of questions out there about creating bounds for the actual map and searching through markers for those within a drawn rectangle, but I have not found an answer for how to specifically search within bounds set by two points I have set through previous searches. I apologize if I missed this somehow! 
Basically, I want to set a start and end point, and map all the options along the route.

I query the first location and set the marker and a LatLng object. I do the same for the end point location marker and LatLng object. Those both work well. When I console.log each of those LatLng objects, they do have latitudes and longitudes set.

The problem comes in when I then attempt to pass those two LatLng variables into the new google.maps.LatLngBounds() object:

```
var searchParameters = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(startPointLatLng), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(endPointLatLng));
```

My console.log(searchParameters) returns errors, so my nearbySearch does not return any results.

```
console.log(searchParameters);

    var requestOptions = {
        bounds: searchParameters,
        types: searchType,
        keyword: 'dog'
        // bounds: map.getBounds(),
    };
    service.nearbySearch(requestOptions, callOptions);
```

The "bounds: map.getBounds()" line does work when not commented out, and returns places and markers across the whole of the map.

Am I creating this LatLngBounds object correctly? Why would the variables suddenly not be defined? I feel like this is a very simple mistake I am overlooking. Also I attempted a JSfiddle but perhaps with the api... it is not showing up. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/y55bejvk/) is the link for all my JS code.. Thank you! Again, I apologize if I'm not doing something correctly for StackOverflow etiquette; I am new.

Comment: how are you creating `startPointLatLng` and `endPointLatLng`?

Comment: Your fiddler isn't working.. "google is not defined"

Comment: [Updated fiddle (shows map)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y55bejvk/1/), the google.maps.LatLng constructor requires two numbers, the google.maps.LatLngBounds requires the two LatLng arguments to be in a specific order ([LatLngBounds(sw?:LatLng, ne?:LatLng)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds)).

Comment: So they cannot be simply the two defined points from the search.. I'll have to create the two specific SW and NE points from the lat and lng values. Ok. Thank you!